How to achieve the layout of figure with vertical and horizonal placement?
I want to achieve the following layout of combined figures.
The requirement is below:

use the package such subcaption to arrange the figures
Align both the top and the bottom line of the Left Big Figure, the Right upper figure and the Right lower three figures automatically(what I mean is that I needn't configured the parameters manually)


I try my best to use minipage and get the very first attempt as the following mwe:
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 7cm]{example-image}
        \caption{firework-big}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 8cm,height =2.5cm]{example-image}
        \caption{example-image}
        \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{1.2cm}
        \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm]{example-image-b}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{1.2cm}
        \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm]{example-image-c}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{three-small-figures}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{total-big-caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I also try to nest the subcaptionblock environment, but failed in arranging the figures.
Thanks for yr help!

Just curious: is this a homework exercise or something? Or what's the source of the 'requirement'?

Can we adjust the size of the images, or just play iwth the gaps?

@cfr It is actually an exercise for me to practice coding with TeX. The requirements purposed just from my brain to 'torture' myself.

@JohnKormylo The proportion of the length and width is not important, I just wonder is there good methods to align the top line and the bottom line to both figures. In a word, we can just adjust the scale of each sub-figure,or just adjust the gap.

What's more, as I known, use the R language, it offer the option to create the layout like that, but if I generate the figure with R or other, it will lose the two-way references to each sub-figures (we can only \ref the whole figure's caption).

If the requirement is quite tough, I am sorry about that. But in my opinion, I am not the first one to put forward requirement like this, and my there exists useful packages? Thanks!

To align the tops and bottoms of the figures would require measuing the fixed heights and adjusting what was left.  In this case, one would have to shrink the images on the right or expand the image on the left.

The thing is, this is a very artificial problem because you would never normally want to scale images regardless of their proportions as that leads to distortion. So you really want to keep the width/height ratios unchanged, but then the task is impossible (or would depend on having suitable images) if alignment includes aligning the images and not just the captions. If you just want to align the tops of the top images and the baselines of the bottom captions, there is no problem. subcaption can do that for you out-of-the-box.

This solution uses a tabular to align what can be aligned without changing the images.
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt}\centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \smash{\includegraphics[width = 7cm, valign=t]{example-image}} &
        \includegraphics[width = 8cm,height =2.5cm, valign=t]{example-image} \\
        & \parbox[b]{8cm}{\subcaption{example-image}} \\
        & \parbox[b]{8cm}{\includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm, valign=t]{example-image-a} 
          \hfill \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm, valign=t]{example-image-b}
          \hfill \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm, valign=t]{example-image-c}} \\
        \parbox[b]{7cm}{\subcaption{firework-big}} &
        \parbox[b]{8cm}{\subcaption{three-small-figures}}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{total-big-caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



This version enlarges the left image to match the right.  Since they are the same height, it doesn't matter whether you align the top, bottom or center.
Using a \vbox instead of a minipage probably has no effect.  I was worried that putting a minipage inside a minipage might change the spacing.
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \setbox1=\vbox{\hsize=8cm % measure height needed
    \includegraphics[width = \hsize,height =2.5cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{example-image}
    \vskip\floatsep% normal spacing between floats
    \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm]{example-image-a} 
      \hfill \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm]{example-image-b}
      \hfill \includegraphics[width = 1.8cm,height =2.5cm]{example-image-c}}%
  \sbox3{\includegraphics[height={\dimexpr \ht1+\dp1}]{example-image}}% measure width needed
  \begin{minipage}{\wd3}
    \usebox3
    \subcaption{example-image}
  \end{minipage}\hfil
  \begin{minipage}{8cm}
    \unvbox1
    \subcaption{three-small-figures}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{total-big-caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


